# Call Apex method in Playground

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'd like to know how can I import an apex class in my Org in a Playground project. I have already logged in my org but when I'm trying to import my apex class, I got this error:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi dibocor, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Any time you get an error message, you should include it in your question ***verbatim***. Please **[edit]** this post to do so, or it will most likely be closed.

Comment: Please include any errors as *text*, rather than images. The former is searchable and accessible to screen readers and other such devices. The latter is neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, you cannot call apex methods from [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground).

This is documented in the **Playground Limitations** section on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.install_playground) (emphasis mine).

> The playground can’t access Salesforce organizations, so it doesn’t support features that require data from Salesforce.
>
> For example, the playground **doesn’t support the wire service, Apex methods**, scoped `@salesforce` modules, or components that require a record ID, like `lightning-record-form`, `lightning-record-view-form`, and  `lightning-record-edit-form`.